# Python 3.7 + Ansible = clang errors

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

First, delete and recreate a fresh virtualenv. This works fine:

```
rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs/test
python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/test
```

As soon as I try to install the pip library `ansible`, I get clang compilation errors. There is a large amount of compiler output to the console that I'm editing out for simplicity. I suspect this isn't an issue with my local environment, but a software compatibility issue with Python 3.7.

```
vex --path ~/.virtualenvs/test pip install ansible

<snip>
ext/_yaml.c:24143:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
        *type = tstate->exc_type;
                        ~~~~~~  ^
<snip>
51 warnings and 15 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with `cython`. There are many similar issues reported on GitHub for some famous libraries like `scikit-learn`, `pandas` etc. Considering creating an issue in [Ansible repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible).

Also see:

- https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1955